# geany will not let me use the "endl;" when using c++

Tags: c++

every time I try to compile it I get an error message along the lines of

> "exercise3.cpp:10:49: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’"

and if I add the `;` before `endl` I get the error message

> "exercise3.cpp:8:71: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function"

I have no idea what the problem is with this, so any help would be appreciated.

code: (sorry about not being lined right but i assure you that it is.)

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    cout << "hello there!\n";
    cout << "here is 5: "<< 5 << "\n";
    cout << "the manipulator end1 wrotes a new line to the screen."; endl;
    cout << "here is a very bug number:\t" << 70000 endl;
    cout << "here is the sum of 8 and 5:\t" << 8+5 endl;
    cout << "heres a fraction:\t\t" << (float) 5/8 endl;
    cout << "and a very big number:\t" << (double) 70000*70000 endl;
    cout << "you really dont have to type this line XD\n";
    cout << "or this one :P cause its not really needed!\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: At the very least line 8. This is likely nothing to do with `endl` or geany. possibly `std::` is missing

Comment: Try `std::endl` or `using namespace std` somewhere

Comment: `iostream` is a standard library header, you should be using angle brackets instead of quotes like so: `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert `<<` before `endl`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << "the manipulator end1 wrotes a new line to the screen."; endl;
```

Should be

```
cout << "the manipulator end1 wrotes a new line to the screen." << endl;
```

And so on

Comment: well the book i am using said to do that too and i got the "not expected in this form" or something,but maybe i just made a typo

Answer (score 1):

You need << before each endl.